# Is there a common symbol for concatenating two (finite) sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Say we have two finite sequences $X = (x_0,...,x_n)$ and $Y = (y_0,...,y_n)$.
Is there a more or less common notation for the concatenation of these sequences, like $\sum (X,Y) = (x_0,...,x_n,y_0,...,y_n)$?

Comment: In fact I meant a symbol for two named sequences, where it is not clear what their content looks like. I changed the question correspondingly.

Comment: I have seen more notations for this, the easiest is $XY$..

Comment: Depending on context, I have seen $XY$, $X\cdot Y$, and $X^{\frown}Y$.

Comment: Yes, probably this $X{}^\frown Y$ is the symbol you are looking for.

Comment: I have seen $X||Y$.

Comment: I've seen lots of notations, but I prefer $X^\frown Y$ because it doesn't seem to be used for anything else.

Comment: @RonGordon I was taught recently that the notation $X||Y$ means *$X$ is parallel to $Y$*

Comment: In computer science I have often seen . used as concatenation, like $X.Y$

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The comments suggest the following notations for the concatenation of $X$ and $Y$:

- $X^\frown Y$ (given by `X^\frown Y`);
- $XY$ (given by `XY`);
- $X \cdot Y$ (given by `X \cdot Y`);
- $X \mathbin\Vert Y$ (given by `X \mathbin\Vert Y`);

of which the first seems not to be in use for other concepts, making it especially suitable.

Comment: What about concatenation from i=1 to N vectors?

Comment: @Pedro77 How about $\big\Vert_{i=1}^N v_i = v_1 \Vert \dots \Vert v_N$?

Comment: I would personally definitely avoid $X\cdot Y$, as that easily can be misinterpreted as the dot product. But hey, maybe it's obvious what is meant given the context.

Comment: This answer sums up pretty well my problem with mathematical formalism. Even the most ridiculously trivial things are hard to find a clear answer to.

Comment: @Johan: That is why I began to define the heck out of everything, including notation, in my publications.

Answer (score 19):

[The same question on Tex SE.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8397/string-vector-concatenation-symbol)

From there, and more:

- $X \oplus Y$ (given by `X \oplus Y`);
- $(X,Y)$ (given by `(X,Y)`);

I would avoid $X \times Y$, $XY$ or $X \cdot Y$ to not confuse it with any sort of multiplication / product.

And I would also not use $X \otimes Y$ because it is usually the tensor product. (See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31518/what-does-the-symbol-otimes-mean).)

Some relevant Wikipedia pages with common notations:

- [Vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Direct_product_and_direct_sum)
- [Direct sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum)
- [Tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product)

Comment: I would avoid `(X, Y)` for concatenation, as it conflicts with the notation used for sequences `(x_0, ..., x_n)`; appearing to be a sequence containing two sequences.

Comment: Wouldn't $X\times Y$ be the *Cartesian Product* of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Wouldn't $\oplus$ be confused for XOR?

Answer (score 14):

$\newcommand\mdoubleplus{\mathbin{+\mkern-10mu+}}$
In haskell the $ \mdoubleplus $ operator is used for concatenating lists.

You can define it in latex using the command

```
\newcommand\mdoubleplus{\mathbin{+\mkern-10mu+}}
```

Comment: You'd have to pay your secretary a lot more to type all that for one symbol. :)

Comment: @user254665 That would be written once, at the top of the document, and thereafter `\mdoubleplus` can be used.

Comment: The ⧺ symbol is `\doubleplus` in the packages unicode-math, stix and stix2.

Comment: I haven't used haskell, but how do you even type that symbol (when programming in haskell)?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye like `++`

Answer (score 10):

Computer science often uses the ⧺ (U+29FA) symbol for concatenation.

This is `\doubleplus` in the LaTeX package unicode-math (which requires a modern engine that supports Unicode), as well as the legacy packages stix and stix2. Or, in the modern toolchain, you can use the Unicode symbol in your source.

Answer (score 5):

If $x$ and $y$ are finite sequences, you could denote their concatenation by $xy$. Let me explain. There's at least two ways of formalizing the statement "$x$ and $y$ are finite sequences in $X$"

- $x$ and $y$ are functions of type $[\:\!n) \rightarrow X$, where $[\:\!n)$ is a shorthand for the set $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$.
- $x$ and $y$ are elements of $X^*$, where $X^*$ is the [monoid freely generated by](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) $X$.

If you're interested in concatenating these things, then you should probably take the second perspective, in which case the concatenation of $x$ and $y$ is simply their product in the monoid $X^*$, which is denoted $xy$.

Answer (score 4):

In formal specifications, one way to concatenate two sequences is using the Haskell concatenation symbol as indicated in one of the comments above. In a $\mathrm\TeX$ editor one can type the following:   `X +\!\!\!+ Y`. The result appears like this, $X+\!\!\!+Y$.

Comment: i didn't know about `\!`. thanks\!!

Answer (score 3):

Starting with your defined sequences $X = (x_0, \ldots, x_n)$ and $Y=(y_0,\ldots,y_n)$, you can use the commonly accepted [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)/[ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair) notation:
\begin{align}
   (X,Y) &= \left(
    \left(x_0,\ldots,x_n\right),
    \left(y_0,\ldots,y_n\right)
   \right)
   \\
   &= \left(x_0,\ldots,x_n,y_0,\ldots,y_n\right)
  \end{align}

Comment: Can you please explain reasoning for downvote; I'd like the opportunity to learn from my mistake.

Comment: The question is asking for a "symbol" which is basically just a single character, not a notation as in your answer.

Comment: A tuple of two sequences is something different than a single sequence (after concatenation).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the $\frown$ (like the $\smile$) are used in algebraic topology for the cap (cup) product, so there is another use for this symbol.  I haven't seen $\uplus$ suggested and I have searched extensively to find an existing use without success.  It seems especially suited because sequences are in fact index-ordered sets which can contain duplicate elements.  Concatenation is the union of such sets which preserves the order of concatenation and allows duplicates.

Comment: I have seen the symbol being used as the [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union).