# Joining finite sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

How do I describe the joining of two finite sequences in mathematical notation? For example, suppose the following:

$$
A=(a_i)_{i=1,2}=(4,2)\\
B=(b_i)_{i=1,2}=(9,5)\\
C=(c_i)_{i=1,...,4}=(4,2,9,5)
$$

Sequence $C$ can be considered sequence $A$ with sequence $B$ attached to the end. How do I describe sequence $C$ in terms of sequence $A$ and $B$?

Comment: It's the concatenation.

Comment: $C= A \cup B$. There is no "attaching to the end". Sets are not ordered.

Comment: @mjb I'm a bit confused. Why wouldn't a sequence be considered ordered?

Comment: @VilhelmGray See my answer below. Sequences are ordered, sets are not. Your notation suggests you mean sets.

Comment: Cf. [#298648](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/298648/43351).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are sets, not sequences. If you ment sets, then it is $C = A \cup B$, the union of the two sets.

If you ment finite sequences you could write \begin{equation} c_i = \begin{cases} a_i & i=1,2 \\ b_{i-2} & i=3,4  \end{cases} \end{equation}

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have inadvertently used the notation for sets; I do mean sequences however. I want to correct the notation in my question, but I'm not sure what the correct notation for sequences are -- do I just remove the curly braces?

Comment: Then the correct notation would be: $A=(a_i)_{i=1,2}=(4,2)$, $B=(b_i)_{i=1,2}=(9,5)$ and $C=(c_i)_{i=1,\ldots,4}$ with $c_i$ defined as above.

Comment: There are of course more complicated notations by interpreting those sequences as functions $\lbrace 1,2 \rbrace \to \mathbb{R}$ or as aborting elements of $\ell^\infty$.