# Which is the best notation for a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, convention

In a set, the order of its elements is (as far as I know) not important; in a sequence, the order of its elements *is* important.

Which is the notation I should use in order to define a sequence? I could denote the sequence of positive integers by $S$.

Now, suppose I want to list (in order) the terms of sequence $S$. I'm not sure if the notation

$$S=\{1, 2, 3, 4, ...\}$$

is appropriate. Besides, I'm not sure if using $=$ is appropriate.

Any comments?

Comment: When you say "sequence of positive integers" do you mean the sequence $S=(s_i)_{i\geq 1}=(s_1,s_2,s_3,\ldots,s_i,\ldots)$ such that $s_i=i$ for all $i\geq 1$? Or, do you just mean the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. They are different things.

Comment: The set $\{1,2,3,4,5\ldots\}$ is equal to $\{2,1,3,4,5,\ldots\}$. However, the sequence $(1,2,3,4,5\ldots)$ is *not* equal to $(2,1,3,4,5,\ldots)$.

Comment: So basically you're saying that curly braces are used for sets and parentheses are used for sequences?

Comment: Yep! And order matters for sequences but not for sets.

Comment: Ok, so that means I could write $$S=(1,2,3,4,...)$$. Is this right?

Comment: If you specifically want the elements to be in that order, then yes. If the order matters, or you want to repeat elements (such as $(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4\ldots)$) then stick to sequences. If you don't care about order or knowing if any elements have been repeated, then use sets.

Comment: Thank you again! Now suppose that $(19,20)$, $(29,30)$, $(39,40)$ are three sequences that form another sequence, which we will denote by $T$. How do you express the fact that $T$ is made up of those three sequences in a specific order? Would it be correct to write $$T=((19,20),(29,30),(39,40))$$?

Comment: In other words, are the expressions $T=((19,20),(29,30),(39,40))$ and $T=(19,20,29,30,39,40)$ equivalent?

Comment: A sequence has infinitely many component elements, we normally call an ordered finite set of elements a 'tuple'. You can think of an infinite tuple as being a sequence.

Comment: So I guess I can think that a sequence (which has infinitely many component elements) is made up of infinitely many tuples. So this means that $T=((19,20),(29,30),(39,40))$ is the same as $T=(19,20,29,30,39,40)$. Am I right?

Comment: Not really, two sequences $s=(s_i)_{i\geq 0}=(s_0,s_1,s_2,\ldots)$ and $t=(t_i)_{i\geq 0}=(t_0,t_1,t_2,\ldots)$ are defined to be equal if and only if $s_i=t_i$ for all $i\geq 0$. It is similar for tuples. In your case, for the first you have $s_0=(19,20)$ but for the second you have $t_0=19$ and so they are not equal.

Comment: I see, you're right. I think I'm not asking the right question. Maybe I'll ask my question later on.

Comment: I would suggest just googling the specific definitions of sets and sequences and what it means for them to be equal. If you have not taken a course which introduces you to set theory notation, it may be a steep curve due to the abstraction involved (specifically sets of sets).

Comment: I think [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298648/is-there-a-common-symbol-for-concatenating-two-finite-sequences) is what I'm looking for (concatenation of sequences).

Comment: According to the comments [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298648/is-there-a-common-symbol-for-concatenating-two-finite-sequences), it seems that the expressions $T=(19,20,29,30,39,40)$ and $T=(19,20)^\frown (29,30)^\frown (39,40)$ are equivalent, but I'm not sure if the symbol $^\frown$ is widely known and/or accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can denote the sequence by $$S =  \{a_k\}_{k = 1}^\infty $$ where $a_k = k$.

Comment: The braces $\{\}$ are confusing here. Normally we use brackets $()$ such as $S=(a_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$.

Comment: I use {} brackets though.

Comment: @DanielRust If one makes it clear one is talking about a sequence, then it should be fine. One might also talk about the sequence $\{(k,a_k):k=0,1,2,\ldots\}$, but then one is more succinct and write $a_k$ instead of $(k,a_k)$.