# Notation concatenation of tuples

Tags: notation

Is there any common notation for concatenating two tuples?

For instance, let's assume we have two tuples $X:=(x_1, \ldots ,x_n )$ and $Y:=(y_1, \ldots ,y_m)$. I want the resulting tuple to be $Z:=(x_1, \ldots ,x_n , y_1, \ldots ,y_m)$.

For sequences, I have read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298648/is-there-a-common-symbol-for-concatenating-two-finite-sequences) that one possibility is to use $\frown$ (`\frown`).

Is this used for tuples as well, such that $Z:=X\frown Y$ would work?

Answer (score 0):

Tuples and sequences are the same thing, so it seems to me that this question is basically a duplicate of the previous one. But in any case I disagree with the accepted answer. I have never seen $\frown$ used in this way. In mathematics I would use $\times$ for the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) here. I would notate individual tuples with lowercase letters and reserve uppercase letters for sets, so $x = (x_1, \dots x_n)$ and $y = (y_1, \dots y_m)$ give $x \times y = (x_1, \dots x_n, y_1, \dots y_m)$.

If the $x_i$ and $y_i$ are vectors in vector spaces you can also use $\oplus$ for the [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum).

Comment: I disagree. I've seen $\frown$ or $\smallfrown$ used for concatenation before, and don't recall seeing $\times$ overloaded in this way. An internet search for, say, `\frown concatenation` brought me five independent sources using it that way on the first page of results alone, including two textbook references.

Comment: @Mark: it's a special case of what I think is a reasonably standard overloading of $\times$ to refer to the operation which given functions $f : X \to Y, g : Z \to W$ produces the function $f \times g : X \times Z \to Y \times W$. This is in turn a special case of a reasonably standard overloading of a functor to act on morphisms with the same symbol it acts on objects, which is most frequently used for the tensor product. I find $\frown$ both ugly and unintuitive but I suppose it at least has the benefit of not having other common meanings.