# Notation: Can matrix summation or matrix multiplication be notated with big- Sigma or Pi, respectively?

Tags: matrices, summation, notation, products

## Summary

I am looking for a general answer to this question about using $\sum$ or $\prod$ notation for matrices.

### Sum

When adding a finite sequence of $n \times m$ matrices, I see that the typical notation is:
$$
A_1+A_2+ \ldots +A_k
$$

Can I use Sigma notation to shorten this?
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k}{A_i} = A_1+A_2+ \ldots +A_k
$$

### Product

Similarly for matrix multiplication, when multiplying a finite sequence of $\require{cancel} \cancel{n \times m}$ (EDIT) $n \times n$ matrices can the following notation be used unambiguously?:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^k {A_i} = A_i A_2 \ldots A_k
$$
And in the reverse order (because matrix multiplication is not commutative):
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} {A_{k-i}} = A_k A_{k-1} \ldots A_1
$$

EDIT:
Per the comments, the ordering is important and can be inferred to be from left to right (thanks @Evariste), as in the [general definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_pi_notation). A suggestion by @Lazy is to explicitly define an index set and iterate on those elements. Would explicit clarity like that help people understand the intention when using this notation?

#### Prior Research

Because [matrix multiplication is not commutative, is associative, and is notated by juxtaposition](https://www.themathcitadel.com/concatenation-as-an-operation/), then I began to wonder if some sort of notation for concatenation of a sequence would be more suitable than [$\prod$ notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Properties_of_capital_pi_notation)

[This comment suggests a similar notation but for concatenation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298648/is-there-a-common-symbol-for-concatenating-two-finite-sequences#comment5893524_423602), so if I went that route, then:
$$
\big\Vert_{i=1}^k {A_i} = A_i A_2 \ldots A_k
$$
And in the reverse order:
$$
\big\Vert_{i=0}^{k-1} {A_{k-i}} = A_k A_{k-1} \ldots A_1
$$
However, I like that *even less* than the "$\ldots$" notation for matrices.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would say yes as long as it makes sense. For the product, you would need $n=m$ for this to work. Perhaps some people could be confused by the non-commutativity so it might be best to use it sparingly or at least give the definition, but the intuitive interpretation of going from left to right in the chronological order makes sense to me.

Comment: Sure, why not, if there is a benefit to it. Note that the product does not make sense in your case, you need $n_1\times n_2$, $n_2\times n_3$, ... so that the dimensions work. Also note the the product only makes sense if you specify the order, so product like
$$ \prod_{i\in I} A_i$$
for some index set $I$ does not make any sense (unless all $A_i$ commute).

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. I updated the question. If you can, I think your comments would be suitable answers.